# cURL post to HTTPCLient C#

Tags: c#, curl, dotnet-httpclient

I'm trying to post a file to PushBullet API service.

The info site of the API shows an example:

```
curl -i https://api.pushbullet.com/api/pushes \
-u API_KEY:
-F device_iden=u1qSJddxeKwOGuGW
-F type=file
-F file=@test.txt
```

And I'm trying to do it with `HttpClient` from C#

I know how to post a file using `Httpclient`, using `MultipartFormDataContent`, but how can I add the device_iden and type info to the client?

I'm using this

```
using (var content = new MultipartFormDataContent())
            {
                try
                {
                    content.Add(new StreamContent(new FileStream(pathFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)));
                    var resp = wc.PostAsync(new Uri(baseUri, "api/pushes"), content);

                }
                catch (Exception)
                {

                    throw;
                }
            }
```

[[New Added]]

Using cURL and fiddler this would be the POST

```
POST http://\/ HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Basic d45YQkxueWswSmxQRTYFjc1deUzNo8UtueVZpaktIZm34anVqdU9NZerWYmFlOp==
User-Agent: curl/7.33.0
Host: \
Accept: */*
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 787
Expect: 100-continue
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------886f3981539a91b3

--------------------------886f3981539a91b3
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="device_iden"

ujuOMfjVbaedjz7O3P0Jl6
--------------------------886f3981539a91b3
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="type"

file
--------------------------886f3981539a91b3
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="img.gif"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
GIF89a������@�;A�;A�;A�;B�<B�<������!�Created with GIMP�!�
��,����������x�����I��8KȻ�`(�$��h��l{�p�tm߮��x����P,���҃l:q���I���؅u�Mf����
��d�y}LG��{���J�>���W};������^�1�����������

--------------------------886f3981539a91b3--
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After trying with fiddler finally could make that post:

First:

```
public static void PushFile(string pathFile, string iddev)
        {         
            string name = Path.GetFileName(pathFile);
            using (var wc = GetClient())
            {
                using (var multiPartCont = new MultipartFormDataContent())
                {
                    multiPartCont.Add(addStringContent("device_iden", iddev));
                    multiPartCont.Add(addStringContent("type","file"));
                    multiPartCont.Add(addStreamContent(new FileStream(pathFile,FileMode.Open),name ));

                    try
                    {
                        var resp = wc.PostAsync(new Uri(baseUri, "api/pushes"), multiPartCont);
                        Task<string> result = resp.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        //string resultado = result.Result;
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                }
            }            
        }
```

Then methods to create the string content and stream content

```
private static StreamContent addStreamContent(Stream stream, string filename )
    {
        var fileContent = new StreamContent(stream);
        fileContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data")
        {
            Name = "\"file\"",
            FileName = "\""+filename+"\""
        };
        fileContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
        return fileContent;
    }
private static StringContent addStringContent(string name, string content)
{
    var fileContent = new StringContent(content);
    fileContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data")
    {
        Name = "\"" + name + "\""
    };
    return fileContent;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I can't bring myself to +1 a post that has two methods with nearly identical signatures, with the same meaningless name, but different capitalization.  AddContent and addContent ... really? :-)

Answer (score 0):

The -u in curl is the http authentication. It looks like pushbullet wants you to login with your API key. Using httpclient you would use;

```
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = CreateBasicHeader("username", "password");
```

The rest would be GET or POST variables (I'm not sure what pushbullet is expecting). It looks like in your code you have it setup with a POST. So you would append to your "content" variable with;

```
 "device_iden=u1qSJddxeKwOGuGW&type=file";
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to create the `-u` data is to create a `HttpClientHandler` with `NetworkCredential`

```
var handler = new HttpClientHandler
{
    Credentials = new NetworkCredential(API_KEY, "")
};

var client = new HttpClient(handler);
```

This will create a basic http authentication header